# Redirecting multiple Urls from a single virtual host in Apache

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

I have hosted 4 managed servers using weblogic in my local system, I want to redirect the webrequests to them using apache , Although I have achieved it but presently I did it using 4 virtual hosts which I don't think so is that much efficient way to do .

Therefore I want to redirect to these 4 managed servers using single virtual host , maybe on the basis of some aliases if possible .

Following is the work which I have done till now:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
Redirect / http://samplehost:16200/cs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8081>
Redirect / http://samplehost:16250/ibr
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8082>
Redirect / http://samplehost:16225/wcc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8083>
Redirect / http://samplehost:16400/cpt
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any way through which I can club these to a single virtual host ?, any way out ? may be using server name or aliases whichever could help.

I tried to achieve this using RewriteRule but it did not worked well, following is that code:

```
 <VirtualHost *:84>

  RewriteEngine on

  /
  RewriteRule "^/$" "http://www.google.co.in" [R,L]
  RewriteRule "^/am/?$" "http://www.amazon.co.in" [R,L]
  RewriteRule "^/fk/.+" "http://www.flipkart.co.in" [R,L]

 </VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for help in advance , I am still brushing my concepts of Apache, any help would be great to have !!!

Comment: You need to 1. tell that virtual host to listen to all relevant host names (ServerAlias), 2. you need to remove other virtual hosts being in the name of the new virtual host responding to those host names and 3. you need to use a `RewriteCond` to test for the host name in the actual rewrite configuration. You get bonus points for _not_ using a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") but the real host configuration.

Comment: Thanks arkascha !! I have almost find a way out with your help , will be uploading  my answer soon , also have learnt lot more things .  Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way out which works like a charm now , lets see how it looks:

```
<VirtualHost samplehost:80>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cs/ 
Redirect / http://samplehost:16200/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ibr/ 
Redirect / http://samplehost:16250/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wcc/ 
Redirect / http://samplehost:16225/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cpt/ 
Redirect / http://samplehost:16400/

</VirtualHost>
```

Because of this I even do not have to remember the port numbers for different virtual hosts.

While Doing this I even find another solution too , it looks like this:

```
  <VirtualHost samplehost:80>


  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule "^/cs/?$" "http://samplehost:16200/cs" [R,L]
  RewriteRule "^/ibr/?$" "http://samplehost:16250/ibr" [R,L]
  RewriteRule "^/wcc/?$" "http://samplehost:16225/wcc" [R,L]
  RewriteRule "^/cpt/?$" "http://samplehost:16400/cpt" [R,L]

  </VirtualHost>
```

Both the solutions are exceptionally well , thanks to @arkascha who brought RewriteCond to my attention.

Thanks for help!!!